# [FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I just updated to Parse 1.9.1 and FBSDK v4.x. Didn't change any code and added to my `.plist` all the App Transport Security keys as required by Facebook. Other than that, didn't change a thing.

Why am I getting this error? I'm logging in with `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`, but I'm getting an unrecognized selector sent to instance with the `logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController` parameter. None of the Parse docs say anything about `fromViewController`. So how can I get my FBLogin back??

Comment: From what version did you update? Did you check the changelogs if you should update any related code?

Comment: exactly from what version of FB you updated to which new version?

Answer (score -1):

Remove fromViewController:, from above code. like:

```
[fbLogin logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error).
```